# C printf using %d and %f

Tags: c, printing, floating-point, double, printf

I was working on this program and I noticed that using %f for a double and %d for a float gives me something completely different. Anybody knows why this happens?

```
int main ()
{
 float a = 1F;
 double b = 1;

 printf("float =%d\ndouble= %f", a, b);
}
```

This is the output

```
float = -1610612736
double = 190359837192766135921612671364749893774625551025007120912096639276776057269784974988808792093423962875123204096.0000
```

Comment: See the C11 specification for [§7.21.6.1 The `printf` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) (or the POSIX specification for [`fprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html)) for information about how to use `printf()` correctly and also [§6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶6 and 7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) about the way floating point arguments are passed to variadic functions.  Modern C compilers like GCC and Clang readily provide extensive diagnostics for format mismatches — you should enable compilation warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way variable parameters work, C has no idea of the type of value you are actually passing it other than `%d` and `%f`. When you pass in a variable parameter you are basically doing `(void*)&myvalue` because neither the compiler, nor the function at run time can determine the type of the variable except for what is given in the formatting string. So even though there is an implicit conversion available, the compiler does not know it is needed.

Well, double is 8 bytes on most systems while float is 4 bytes. So the two types are not binary compatible as it is. And it is like trying to interpret a string as a double, or some other incompatible type.

Comment: Correct, but it is not really about compatibility between `float` and `double` specifically. Actually, variadic arguments of `float` type are always promoted to `double` before passing, meaning that `float` type is not involved into anything here. Both values that are passed to `printf` have `double` type. Inside the first one is interpreted as an `int` (because of `%d` specifier). The incompatibility between `int` and `double` is what's causing the observed undefined behavior.

Comment: With a variadic function such as `printf()`, any `float` value passed as part of the variable argument list is automatically converted to `double` (see C11 [§6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶6 & 7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6)).

Comment: I really can't agree with "you are basically doing `(void *)&myvalue`" — the values are passed as values, not as pointers.

Answer (score 6):

`%d` stands for decimal and it expects an argument of type `int` (or some smaller signed integer type that then gets promoted). Floating-point types `float` and `double` both get passed the same way (promoted to `double`) and both of them use `%f`. In C99 you can also use `%lf` to signify the larger size of `double`, but this is purely cosmetic (notice that with `scanf` no promotion occurs and this actually makes a difference).

Comment: Well, this is true http://codepad.org/labE8lgy but I do wonder how that actually works..

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with internal representations of data. You are trying to print a float as if it is an int, which has a completely different internal (binary) representation.

The **double** case is similar. You probably have garbage (any data) after the float variable. That garbage is interpreted as part of the double value.

Answer (score 1):

%d prints an integer, so your printf is interpreting your variable a as an int.

With gcc 3.4.6, I get 0's for both values with your code (after taking the F off the a initialization, as that led to a compiler error).  I suspect this has to do with the part of the a variable that is being interpreted as an int being 0, and then the compiler gets confused ... (there's probably a better explanation, but I can't think of it).

Using %f for both variable prints 1.000000 for both variables for me.

You can find a list of the conversion characters near the bottom this page:

http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/managing-input-and-output-operations-in-c.html

Comment: The compiler error associated with `F` is because it cannot be attached to an integer (e.g., `1.0F` is fine).