# Scanning data into a multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was given data from a file that included mass and the (x,y,z) position of a point. I now want to take the data I was given and output it into a file using a multidimensional array. I don't know how to take scanned data and use that in the array, however.

I have my data stored as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)      //scan in file data
{
    fscanf(fpin, "%d %d %d %d", &array_x[i], &array_y[i], &array_z[i], &array_mass[i]);
}
```

I tried setting my array up as `[][4]` since the number of rows is dependent on the number of data points given (and the instructions were to write an array that would work for any number of data points, not just what was given) and there would be 4 columns (one for x, y, z, and mass respectively).

Then I tried setting it up as:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    array_out[i][4] = { {array_x[i]}, {array_y[i]}, {array_z[i]}, {array_mass[i]} };
}
```

And printing it as:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        fprintf(fpout, "%d %d %d %d", array[i][j]);
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: You can't "set up your array as `[][4]`.  That's meaningless.  You need to allocate memory for it.  SInce the number of data points is variable, you will need to dynamically allocate memory for it.  http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html may be helpful to you.

Comment: Try adding more complete code, specifically, your declaration of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many elements you need to read?  If you do, then you can allocate an array to hold them. If you do not then you need dynamic storage.

What are the types of your mass and point(x,y,z)?  Please provide samples.

You may have issues with your printf format specifier (do you really mean %d, as that is not double)? (see: [C printf using %d and %f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274336/c-printf-using-d-and-f))

Declare a struct to contain your point/mass, and essential functions (methods) to deal with pointmass(es),

Declare storage,

```
typedef struct pointmass_struct {
    double mass;
    double x,y,z;
} pointmass_t ;
```

Declare functions/methods,

```
pointmass_t*
pm_new( double mass, double x, double y, double z ) {
    pointmass_t* this;
    if( ! (this=malloc(sizeof(pointmass_t)) ) return(NULL);
    this->mass = mass;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
    return(this);
}
void
pointmass_del( pointmass_t* pm ) {
    if(pm) free(pm);
    return;
}
pointmass_t*
pointmass_fromstr( char* line ) {
    double x, y, z, m;
    sscanf(line, "%f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &m );
    pointmass_t* this = pointmass_new( x, y, z, m );
    return( this );
}
pointmass_t*
pointmass_fscanf( FILE* fp ) {
    double x, y, z, m;
    fscanf(fp, "%f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &m );
    pointmass_t* this = pointmass_new( x, y, z, m );
    return( this );
}
char*
pointmass_tostr( pointmass_t* this, char* buff ) {
    if( !buff ) return(buff);
    sprintf(buff, "%f %f %f %f", this->x, this->y, this->z, this->mass );
    return(buff);
}
int
pointmass_print( pointmass_t* this )
{
    char pmbuff[100];
    return( printf("%s\n",pointmass_tostr(this,pmbuff) ) );
}
```

Scan one pointmass,

```
pointmass_t* pm = pointmass_fscanf(fpin);
```

Scan many pointmass(es) into a declared array of pointmass,

```
pointmass_t* pm_array[100]; //pick a suitable size
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) //scan point/mass elements from file
{
    pm_array[i] = pointmass_fscanf(fpin);
}

char pmbuff[100];
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) //print them
{
    printf("[%d] %s\n",pointmass_str(pm_array[i],pmbuff));
}
```

Track how large the array is, and dynamically increase the size,

```
pointmass_t** pm_dynarray;
int pmsize = 0;
pm_dynarray = malloc( (pmsize=500) * sizeof(pointmass_t*));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) //scan from file
{
    if( i+1 > pmsize ) {
        pm_dynarray = realloc( (pmsize+=100) * sizeof(pointmass_t*));
    }
    pm_dynarray[i] = pointmass_fscanf(fpin);
}

for(i = 0; i<pmsize; i++ )
{
    printf("[%d] %s\n",i,pointmass_str(pm_dynarray[i],pmbuff));
}
```

Remember to free all of these pointmass elements,

```
for(i = 0; i<pmsize; i++ )
{
    if(pm_dynarray[i]) pointmass_del(pm_dynarray[i]);
    pm_dynarray[i] = NULL;
}
//now safe to free the array
free(pm_dynarray); pm_dynarray=NULL; pmsize=0;
```

Better yet, use a linked list to store the pointmass elements.