# Initialize a double array with int values in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning some c now, and must do an exercise for the university. I need an double array which should be filld with int values. So I've this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

int size=0, i=0;

printf("Enter size of array: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

double* field = malloc(size * sizeof(double));
double value;

for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
    field[i] = i;;
}

for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
    printf("Field%i: %d\n",i, field[i]);
}

free(field);

return 0;
```

}

But, when I execute it all values are set to 0.

```
Enter size of array: 10
Field0: 0
Field1: 0
Field2: 0
Field3: 0
Field4: 0
Field5: 0
Field6: 0
Field7: 0
Field8: 0
Field9: 0
```

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274336/335858) for an explanation.

Comment: Check the warning options for your compiler.  Many compilers can issue a warning for format specifier mismatches - do not ignore warnings - especially do not ask questions about code that is issuing warnings - either ask about the warning specifically or fix the warnings before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf`'s `%d` stands for *decimal integer*, not *double*.

So this line:

```
printf("Field%i: %d\n",i, field[i]);
```

should be:

```
printf("Field%i: %f\n",i, field[i]);
```

Using the wrong format specifier is **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** which you had earlier.

From [**standard**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9)

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

---

Also check the return value of `malloc`. It let's you know whether the allocation failed (returns `NULL`) or not.

<sub>A bit more insight from David C. Rankin's comment</sub>

> <sub>The `%d` format
>   specifier was looking for `4`-bytes (`sizeof int` bytes) in memory
>   ordered based on the endianess of your machine. When you provided an
>   8-byte (`sizeof double`) value comprised of a sign-bit, normalized
>   exponent and mantissa, it had no idea what to do with it.</sub>

<sub>Well here in `printf` we can use `%f` instead of `%lf` also which has added benefit of compatibility with pre-C99 versions and also it is shorter. (chux pointed this).</sub>

Comment: The ole', I'm trying to print an IEEE-754 double-precision floating point value as an `int` and it's not working??

Comment: Just understand, the `%d` *format specifier* was looking for 4-bytes in memory ordered based on the endianess of your machine. When you provided an 8-byte value comprised of a sign-bit, normalized exponent and mantissa, it had no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Sure, you have free license. Use at will.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Well I guess OP's machine is Little Endian and that's why it printed (which is not standard behavior) the 4 bytes of it which is `0`'s. (mantissa is 0's for all these numbers). `8.0`'s representation in hex is `0x4020000000000000`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: It's more correct to say that it is not not defined behavior rather than saying *it's not standard behavior*.. It may have crashed.

Comment: Why recommend `"%lf"` vs. the simpler `"%f"`?  After all the [No-el](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noel) version is more in line with the season.

Comment: @chux.: Well it doesn't matter I guess. On the other hand any reason why you say should go with`%f`? :) :D .

Comment: 1) `"%f"` is shorter 2) `"%lf"` does not work with pre-C99  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4264127/2410359) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210590/2410359)

Comment: @chux.: I was aware of the `scanf` part but was misssing pre-C99 issue...Thanks as always

Answer (score -1):

I don't think whether malloc function allocated the memory for the array. Check the syntax of malloc and also the return type.